# Perl webscript doubtful security

Tags: perl, security, cgi-bin

Recently with a project I inherited a simple perl script that generates a PDF of the page:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use CGI;

my $file="showdata.pdf";
my $filepath= "/tmp/$file";
system("wkhtmltopdf \"sample.com/showdata.php?".$ENV{"QUERY_STRING"}."\" $filepath");
print ("Content-Type:application/x-download\n");
print ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file\n\n");

open FILE, "< $filepath" or die "can't open : $!";
binmode FILE;
local $/ = \10240;
while (<FILE>){
    print $_;
}

close FILE;
unlink ($filepath);
```

I am concerned direct substitution variable $ENV{"QUERY_STRING"}. However, in a cursory testing, I did not reveal any problems. I was not able to create/delete files in a known writable directory. I tried not well or problems in the script should not be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing $ENV{"QUERY_STRING"} directly is insecure. In my case, my digital parameter 'o' must be forced to be integer. There is secure script version:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use CGI;
my $query = new CGI;
my $o = int($query->param('o'));
my $file="showdata.pdf";
my $filepath= "/tmp/$file";
system("wkhtmltopdf \"sample.com/showdata.php?o=".$o."\" $filepath");
print ("Content-Type:application/x-download\n");
print ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file\n\n");

open FILE, "< $filepath" or die "can't open : $!";
binmode FILE;
local $/ = \10240;
while (<FILE>){
    print $_;
}

close FILE;
unlink ($filepath);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's insecure.  What if QUERY_STRING was `"; rm -fr /;`?

Then your `system` call would be:

```
wkhtmltopdf "sample.com/showdata.php?"; rm -fr /; /tmp/showdata.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

If you concern about security, run your Perl script with taint option `-T`.

For example, the following script will halt your script with warning: `Insecure $ENV{PATH} while running with -T switch at ./foo.pl line 4.`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -T

my $foo = $ENV{FOO};
system("ls -l $foo");
```

Note: option `-t` can be used instead of `-T` if you just need warning.